# I want to get pdf with image from google spreadsheet database from google document for the template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I have successfully generated pdf without image but when I  added a picture in my spreadsheet hoping that I can get my picture in my pdf file the script didn't work.
Could anyone help me where is the error in my script?
Please check my script with the label `//try image` that causes my script did not work for generating pdf with image.

```
function buatPdf() {
  var docTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('ID Template');
  var folderTujuan = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID Folder')
  
  //try image
  var replaceTextToImage = function(body, searchText, fileId) {
  var width = 100;
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
  var r = body.findText(searchText).getElement();
  r.asText().setText("");
  var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, blob);
  var w = img.getWidth();
  var h = img.getHeight();
  img.setWidth(width);
  img.setHeight(width * h / w);
  }
 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Data')
        
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){

    if (index === 0) return;
   
    var copy = docTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[0]} ${row[1]}` , folderTujuan)

    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    
    var body = doc.getBody();
    //photo
    var photoImage = (row[2]).split("=")[1]; //try image
    
    body.replaceText('{{IDstd}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Name}}', row[1]);
    replaceTextToImage(body,'{{Photo}}', photoImage);//try image
    body.replaceText('{{Hobby}}', row[4]);
            
    doc.saveAndClose();

})
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your script and your sample image (Spreadsheet), I can confirm the URL of image like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/###,,,` and `const photoImage = (row[2]).split("=")[1];`. In this case, unfortunately, I cannot confirm your whole URL from your image, for example, when the URL is like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/###,,,?key=value`, `photoImage` is `value`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

When I think of the modification point from your current sample image, in order to retrieve the file ID from the URL, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const photoImage = (row[2]).split("=")[1];
```

#### To:

```
const photoImage = (row[2]).split("/")[5];
```

- By this, when your URLs of your sample image is used, the file ID can be retrieved. But, if you don't have the permission for reading the file, an error occurs. Please be careful this.

Comment: @Tanaike..the script works great. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Supartoyo Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Supartoyo From `@Tanaike..the script works great. Thank you very much for your help.`, I had thought that your script worked. But from the current situation, I'm confusing it. Can I ask you about this current situation?